# Why is Google indexing management not applicable to the live version?

Tags: html, git, apache2, google-index

I have a task to prevent Google's crawler from indexing some content. I have read, that if I have this kind of html:

```
<!--googleoff: index-->

<!--googleon: index-->
```

then googleoff tells Google's crawler to not index the content, while googleon tells Google's crawler to index to content. So far, so good. So, the content which should not be indexed by Google's crawler should be between those comments. I have wrapped all the content which should be excluded from Google's indexing into those comments, using the googleoff and googleon feature and all the content to be excluded from Google's indexing is correctly wrapped inside those comments locally and on the staging repo. However, I do not see the comments containing the googleoff and googleon instructions in the HTML of the live version. What could be the cause of this? Why are the google indexing instructions available in all my repos except the live version? I think this might be an issue with the settings, but I am not sure that I am right and I am not sure where should I look for the source of the problem?

Comment: Why not simply use a robots.txt file?

Comment: I want to filter out parts of the content from indexing, not whole pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with server settings, it has been solved. After a while (when reindexing is complete) the undesired content should be filtered out from google indexing.